# Very simple ngModel example

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple form

```html
<form role="form" (submit)="login()">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required="required" [ngModel]="credentials.username"/>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required="required" [ngModel]="credentials.password" />
  <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

and a component ts.

```ts
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  credentials = {username: '', password: ''};
  
  constructor(private loginService: LoginService, private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }
  
  ngOnInit() { }
  
  login() {
    console.log(this.credentials);
    this.loginService.authenticate(this.credentials, () => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
    });
    return false;
  }
}
```

service

```ts
authenticate(credentials, callback) {
  console.log(credentials);
  const headers = new HttpHeaders(credentials ? {
   authorization : 'Basic ' + btoa(credentials.username + ':' + credentials.password)
  } : {});
}
```

My problem is that the credentials are always `''`. Shouldn't the `ngModel` update these values automatically?

Comment: btw this is the tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `[(ngModel)]` to set values like this -

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required="required" [(ngModel)]="credentials.username"/>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" [(ngModel)]="credentials.password" />
```

As of now, you are using `[ngmodel]` which is just attribute binding to set value into your DOM and display it back.

But if you want to update value from view part you should use two way data binding `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: so Have you sort it out now?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[ngModel]`

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required="required" [(ngModel)]="credentials.username"/>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="required" [(ngModel)]="credentials.password" />
```

because `[(` in Angular is signalling a `two-way` *data binding*. Theoretically you could only bind to an event `(ngModel)` or to a value `[ngModel]`. But in this case you need to use `two-way` *data binding* : `[(ngModel)]`